# height 100% breaks across chain

Tags: css

For some reason the height: 100% doesn't work across the entire document. It breaks in the process, and stops taking up 100% of it's parent.

I have the following structure:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <div data-reactroot>
                <header class="header">
                    <nav>...</nav>
                </header>
                <main id="main">
                    <div id="slideshow">...</div>
                    <div id="inner-page">...</div>
                </main>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the following CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

#app, #app>div {
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #263238;
}

#main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#slideshow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    padding: 0 !important;
}

#inner-page {
    width: 100%; 
    position: relative;
    padding: 24px;
}
```

The height gets inherited properly until the `<div data-reactroot>` element (including), but breaks at the `<main>` element, and i can't seem to figure out why. The CSS is pretty straightforward, and i can't seem to get to the bottom of the issue.

**Note:** I omitted the content of the slideshow and the inner page for simplicity, as I believe that level of depth isn't relevant to the issue (or am i wrong?)

Would appreciate any assistance with this puzzle.

Comment: You mean height of main as 100%;

Comment: As we all benefit of knowing which answer solved a specific question, it would be great if you could accept an answer, if any, that solve your question, or let us know what is missing, so we can find one that does

Comment: I figured it out eventually, the problem was that one of the children across the chain had the height 100% overridden by an external library (material-ui),  so height: 100% !important; fixed it.  Thanks for all your suggestions guys

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `100vh` instead of `100%` or if you want to stick to `100%`, add one more selector like this:

```
html, #app, #app>div, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

this should work

Comment: I already have that... I edited my question and added it... it doesn't seem to make a difference. I tried adding using both `100vh`, and `min-height: 100%`. Both don't seem to work...

Comment: Its already working, use background for #app and check the output

Answer (score 0):

Make this changes in your codes, and if it's about the height of `#main` then `height:100%;` wont work as elements that are present inside are positioned as `absolute`.

```
#app{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:#f22;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #263238;
}

#main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background:#ccc;
}
```